# Haskell - I have a question split into 3 parts - using the first 2 functions make a function that sorts a list of tuples on the first elements

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

New to haskell. So the first function I made `sort_by` sorts a list of type a using quicksort - works fine.

Next function compare by takes in a comparator type (defined below) and a function and returns a comparator - so `GT`, `EQ` etc. Both of these functions I had to make using just the function definition. Now the problem - I'm supposed to use both these functions to define a function based on the title using currying, but I don't know how my `compare_By` function is supposed to help create a function like that?

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
import GHC.Show (Show)
type Comparator a   = a -> a -> Ordering
type Tokeniser a    = String -> [a]
type Translator a b = a -> Maybe b

data English = E String deriving (Show)
data French  = F String deriving (Show)
data German  = G String deriving (Show)


sort_by :: Comparator a -> [a] -> [a]
sort_by o as = qs as []
    where qs [] as' = as'
          qs (a:as) as' = qs les $ a : qs gts as'
            where les = [a' | a' <- as, a  `o` a' == GT] 
                  gts = [a' | a' <- as, a `o` a' /= GT]

compare_by :: (b -> a) -> Comparator a -> Comparator b
compare_by f o a b = o (f a) (f b)

sort_by_fst :: Comparator a -> [(a,b)] ->[(a,b)]
sort_by_fst f [(a,b)] = ??
```

Comment: If you want to turn a `Comparator a` into a `Comparator (a,b)`, what type of function do you need to pass to `compare_by`, and can you think of any functions of such a type?

Comment: On an unrelated note, using `[(a,b)]` as a pattern means that your function will only work on single-element lists.

Comment: had as there mb

Answer (score 0):

When faced with these problems it’s helpful to look at the types and work from there.

You need to use `sort_by` and `compare_by` to create `sort_by_fst`. Evidently, we’ll need `sort_by` to sort the list, so let’s see the type of that:

```hs
sort_by :: Comparator a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Great, let’s use that to sort the list:

```hs
sort_by_fst f xs = sort_by _comparator xs
```

Looking at the type of `sort_by` again, we can see we need a `Comparator (a, b)` to sort the `xs :: [(a, b)]`. But we only have a `f :: Comparator a`, so use `compare_by` to get a `Comparator (a, b)`.

```hs
compare_by :: (b -> a) -> Comparator a -> Comparator b
-- Specialising to the types we need (substituting b = (a, b)):
compare_by :: ((a, b) -> a) -> Comparator a -> Comparator (a, b)
```

In addition to a `Comparator a`, we need a `(a, b) -> a`: a function that gets the first element of a tuple. [`fst`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fst) does exactly that:

```hs
sort_by_fst f xs = sort_by (compare_by fst f) xs
```

This could also be written more succinctly as

```hs
sort_by_fst = sort_by . compare_by fst
```

---

By the way, the `_name` (e.g. `_comparator`) syntax is [GHC’s typed holes feature](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/typed_holes.html). If you compile code with a hole, GHC will tell you what type of expression needs to go there and suggests possible bindings (e.g. functions and parameters) that could fill the hole.

---

As a side note, the `compare_by` function is a specialised and flipped version of [`on`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on) from `Data.Function`:

```hs
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
```

`sort_by_fst` could therefore be implemented like this:

```hs
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Function (on)

sort_by_fst :: Comparator a -> [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
sort_by_fst f = sortBy (f `on` fst)
```